# Python: Selenium only runs with admin privileges

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, webdriver, admin

I'm getting this error when I try to run this line:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

It returns this error:

[image]

But it runs successful if I open Visual Studio Code as Administrator.
I'm using Python 3.9.7 (Anaconda)

Is there a way to make this work without having to run VS Code as Admin?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that chrome.exe was running in Administrator mode, I unchecked the option: Google Chrome Properties -> Compatibility-> run as administrator
And finally get it to work!